# Training improvements on new actions builder

Tags: actions-on-google, actions-builder

I am building an new action. I have multiple intents, and I added ~20 training phases for each of them. However the matching seems to be pretty terrible

I have webhooks configured for the scenes. I look at the raw query and the handler that was matched. I have the exact phrase in the training phrases, but a different intent gets matched.

It seems like old Dialogflow interface had a way to improve training (https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/training#tool) allowing you to match actual queries with the right intents. Is there an equivalent tool for the new actions builder?

Comment: Failing to match the Intent seems like the more confusing problem here. You may wish to create a new question that illustrates the problem with screen shots and sample dialog to help us help you diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't (currently) such a tool.

However, it seems odd that a training phrase that was used wouldn't match if the Intent is one that is set to be recognized in a scene (or is a Global Intent).

The last point is the most important - make sure that you have the Intent set to a scene and that you're in that scene when you're attempting to trigger the Intent in question.